# Laravel get method parameters cannot be fetched

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I faced a weird issue in Laravel today, the version am using is Laravel 5.5 and I have defined a route as below in the application.

```
 Route::get('getplaylist/{playlistid}/{page}', 'Mycontroller@getplaylist');
```

And in my controller am trying to fetch the parameters, weirdly

```
dd($request->all()); // results in empty array []
```

whereas the below one works,

```
dd($request->playlistid);
```

Any help would be appreciated on what is happening behind the scenes. The issue am facing is am not able to validate the request since an empty '[]' array is resulted.

Comment: Please share more details. The given route does not contain any GET parameter

Answer (score 2):

Route parameters, like `playlistid` and `page` in your example, can be used with the `$request->route()` method.

Example:

```php
$request->route('playlistid')
```

You can also fetch all route parameters using `$request->route()->parameters()`.

Answer (score 1):

As @erikgaal already mentioned, these are route parameters, not request parameters.

But, as is written in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers), it is one of the most basic and core parts of Laravel, that these route parameters get injected into the controller method. Therefore, with your route:

```php
class Mycontroller 
{
    public function getplaylist(Request $request, $playlistid, $page)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```